# caps lock led not working on Linux console

Tags: linux, console, capslock

When I switch to a TTY and turn on the caps lock, the caps lock LED on my keyboard isn't turning on. On X it works fine. When I activate caps lock and then switch to a TTY and then press caps lock (on the TTY) the LED stays on (Even though the TTY keeps it's own track of the caps lock). So it seems the TTYs don't care about the LED at all.

Can I somehow enable the LED on TTYs? It's very annoying to be forced to type something whilst not knowing if caps lock is activated.

I'm using Debian jessie (frequently updated) arch: amd64

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a long standing Debian [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=514464). It seems to relate to an underlying kernel [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7746) which has been long since fixed. The problem seems to have been that `Caps_Lock` did not work for non-ASCII characters, so the workaround was to map `Shift_Lock` or `CtrlL_Lock` to the caps lock key instead.

On the Debian side the issue is created by `ckbcomp` which is used by `console-setup` to create the console keymap from the XKB keyboard description. Note that the original code referenced in the bug report using `Shift_Lock` seems to have been replaced by different code which switches for `CtrlL_Lock` instead. If you are interested you can search for usages of the `broken_caps` variable in the `ckbcomp` Perl script.

I have no idea if the code is still necessary for any reason, maybe it is worth bumping the bug report. However, the workaround is to put the following line in `/etc/kbd/remap` and it should be fixed after a reboot:

```
s/CtrlL_Lock/Caps_Lock/
```

Or for a temporary fix until the next reboot, run the following in a `tty` session:

```
dumpkeys | sed s/CtrlL_Lock/Caps_Lock/ | sudo loadkeys
```

#### Update

It seems that `/etc/kbd/remap` is only actually used if `setupcon` is not available. A better workaround is just to put the following line in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
dumpkeys | sed s/CtrlL_Lock/Caps_Lock/ | loadkeys
```

Comment: That's strange. The temporary fix works, but the fix in /etc/kbd/remap doesn't work.

Comment: @Kritzefitz updated, `/etc/kbd/remap` is only used in some circumstances.

Comment: And is necessary to remove "exit 0" in the file /etc/rc.local

Comment: @VitorMazuco can you please explain why? It works fine for me with it exiting on zero. Have you not seen the comments at the top of the file? "Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other value on error".

Answer (score 4):

I found solutions for Debian 6 and Debian 7.

#### *Debian 6*

Put the following at the end of the `/etc/console-setup/remap.inc` file:

```
keycode 58 = Caps_Lock
```

Then run `setupcon`

#### *Debian 7*

Put the following at the end of the `/etc/default/keyboard` script:

```
dumpkeys | sed -e "s/keycode  58 = CtrlL_Lock/keycode  58 = Caps_Lock/" | \
   loadkeys 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

Then run `setupcon`

Note that there are two spaces between keycode and 58. The redirect into `/dev/null` just suppresses annoying console output.